# IOS Bar Charts - How to show values (1.0,2.0 etc) label upon Bar Chart & show particular values (like 3 - 7) on Bar Chart Scroll

Tags: ios, swift, bar-chart

I am working On a Bar Chart in iOS Swift

[image: chart]
[image: chart]

Code:

```
let chartDataSet: BarChartDataSet!
chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "Rupee  Date-->")
chartDataSet.colors = [AppColors.barChartColor]
chartDataSet.highlightColor = AppColors.barChartHighlightColor
chartDataSet.valueTextColor = UIColor.black
chartDataSet.values = dataEntries
let chartData = BarChartData(dataSet: chartDataSet)
chartData.setDrawValues(true)
cell.barChartView.drawValueAboveBarEnabled = true
cell.barChartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values:monthDateArray as! [String])
cell.barChartView.animate(xAxisDuration: 1.0, yAxisDuration: 1.0)
cell.barChartView.data = chartData
cell.barChartView.xAxis.granularity = 1.0
cell.barChartView.setVisibleXRange(minXRange: 7, maxXRange: 7)
cell.barChartView.leftAxis.axisMinimum = 0
cell.barChartView.drawValueAboveBarEnabled = true
```

**Questions**

1. How to show values above bars, like 4.0, 3.0 etc.
2. The bar always opens at 0 position. I want the bar to open always at the current date position, and on scrolling, we can show all data.

Comment: Could you add some of data in dataEntries?

Comment: For Label aboove bar use this self.drawValueAboveBarEnabled = true self is BarChartView

Comment: @RazibMollick - Here you can see my data Entries -  0 : ChartDataEntry, x: 1.0, y 4.0
  ▿ 1 : ChartDataEntry, x: 2.0, y 1.0
  ▿ 2 : ChartDataEntry, x: 3.0, y 14.0
  ▿ 3 : ChartDataEntry, x: 4.0, y 2.0
  ▿ 4 : ChartDataEntry, x: 5.0, y 23.0
  ▿ 5 : ChartDataEntry, x: 6.0, y 30.0
  ▿ 6 : ChartDataEntry, x: 7.0, y 6.0
  ▿ 7 : ChartDataEntry, x: 8.0, y 21.0

Comment: @ManishMahajan - I have added line                 chartDataSet.drawValuesEnabled = true, but nothing works.

Comment: @SatyamTayal I am saying self.drawValueAboveBarEnabled = true not drawValuesEnabled

Comment: @ManishMahajan - Hi MAnish Thanks for your reply. But it doesn't works, I have updated my question too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this extension:-

```
//Bar chart extensio to set custom xAxia and yAxis
extension BarChartView {

private class BarChartFormatter: NSObject, IAxisValueFormatter {

    var labels: [String] = []

    func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {
        return labels[Int(value)]
    }

    init(labels: [String]) {
        super.init()
        self.labels = labels
    }
}

func setBarChartData(xValues: [String], yValues: [String], label: String) {

    var dataEntries: [BarChartDataEntry] = []

    for i in 0..<yValues.count {
        let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: Double(yValues[i])!)
        dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
    }

    let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: label)
    chartDataSet.colors = [NSUIColor(red: 0/255.0, green: 110/255.0, blue: 194/255.0, alpha: 1.0)]
    chartDataSet.valueFont = NSUIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13)

    let chartData = BarChartData(dataSet: chartDataSet)
    let chartFormatter = BarChartFormatter(labels: xValues)
    let xAxis = XAxis()
    xAxis.valueFormatter = chartFormatter
    self.xAxis.valueFormatter = xAxis.valueFormatter
    self.drawValueAboveBarEnabled = true

    self.data = chartData
}
}
```

Call function:-

```
@IBOutlet var chartView: BarChartView! 
...
chartView.setBarChartData(xValues: dates, yValues: Leads, label: "Leads")
```

Where dates and Leads are array of strings

Comment: Thanks that worked for me. Can you try with 2nd question too? Like when bar open i want to show from current date to next week.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer for Question 1**

By Mr. Mahajan Code and some with this Functionality:-

Code:

```
 cell.barChartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values:monthDateArray as! [String])
 cell.barChartView.animate(xAxisDuration: 1.0, yAxisDuration: 1.0)
 cell.barChartView.xAxis.granularity = 1.0
 cell.barChartView.setVisibleXRange(minXRange: 7, maxXRange: 7)
 cell.barChartView.leftAxis.axisMinimum = 0
 cell.barChartView.xAxis.granularityEnabled = true
 cell.barChartView.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false                
 cell.barChartView.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
 cell.barChartView.chartDescription?.text = ""  
 cell.barChartView.rightAxis.enabled = false
 cell.barChartView.animate(xAxisDuration: 2.0, yAxisDuration: 2.0, easingOption: .easeInOutQuart)
```

**Answer for Question 2**

Code:

```
            let date = Date()
            let formatter = DateFormatter()
            formatter.dateFormat = "dd"
            let result = formatter.string(from: date)
            var myDoubleX = Double(result)
            myDoubleX = myDoubleX! - 1.5  
            cell.barChartView.moveViewToX(myDoubleX!)
```

Answer (score 0):

SWIFT 4.2

For the [Daniel Gindi](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) Chart if you want to add two different value at the top of the bar candle if you have noticed there are one stand alone properties  in the **BarChartDataEntry** named **icon** you can convert your text in to image and add that image as an icon to populate at the top of the bar candle.

Here I have done the same thing with the **CandleStickChartView** and it's Base class is **BarLineChartViewBase**. You can access this properties in the BarChart too.

Let's focus on the code.

Here I have an array of the BloodPressure Readings which is having Systolic and Diastolic Value. and circulate the loop to make a **CandleChartDataEntry /  BarChartDataEntry**

```
    for (index, bloodPressure) in bloodPressureData.enumerated() {
        let systolicDouble = bloodPressure.value.systolic.doubleValue.rounded(toPlaces: 0)
        let diastolicDouble = bloodPressure.value.diastolic.doubleValue.rounded(toPlaces: 0)
        let high = max(Int(systolicDouble), Int(diastolicDouble))
        let low = min(Int(systolicDouble), Int(diastolicDouble))
        let imageLabel = "  \(Int(systolicDouble))-\(Int(diastolicDouble))  "
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 10))
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.textColor = UIColor.black
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        label.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0
        label.font = UIFont(name: "Montserrat-Regular", size: 8.0)
        label.text = imageLabel
        label.sizeToFit()
        let image = UIImage.imageWithLabel(label: label)
        let dataEntry = CandleChartDataEntry(x: Double(index), shadowH: CGFloat(high), shadowL: CGFloat(low), open: CGFloat(high), close: CGFloat(low), icon: image)
        
        let dataBarEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(index), y: CGFloat(high), icon: image)
        entries.append(dataEntry)

    }
```

Here I have created a separate UIImage **extension** which is rendering UILabel in to UIImage

```
extension UIImage {
    class func imageWithLabel(label: UILabel) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(label.bounds.size, false, 0.0)
        label.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return img!
   }
}
```

by that extension you can covert your text in to image and add that image as an icon while you are preparing your **BarChartDataEntry/CandleChartDataEntry**

Note: To make it clearly visible at the top of the candle you need to set the offset of the icon by using this property

```
let set1 = CandleChartDataSet(entries: entries, label: "Blood Pressure")
set1.iconsOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -8)
set1.drawValuesEnabled = false // Disable drawable value
```

Here I am attaching the outcome of it:

[image]

Thank you